# MSVSMON.exe не может использоваться для отладки 64-разрядных процессов

Tags: c#, visual-studio, x86-64, microsoft-edge, remote-debugging

Я пытаюсь в Visual Studio 2015 отладить своё приложение под 64-разрядный Microsoft Edge в режиме совместимости с Internet Explorer (моё приложение написано под 32-разрядный Internet Explorer).

Я поискал в интернете информацию, как это сделать. Выяснил, что приложению в Configuration Manager нужно изменить Active solution platform на x64. Я это сделал. Пересобрал решение. Запустил отладку, а мне выдало сообщение:

Unable to attach to application 'msedge.exe' (PID: 7804) using
'XXXXXX'. The 32-bit version of the Visual Studio Remote
Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) cannot be used to debug 64-bit
processes or 64-bit dumps. Please use the 64-bit version instead.

Снова полез в интернет. Нашёл инфу, что отладка не работает т.к. IIS Express используемый для отладки, запускается, как 32-разрядный. Там же сказано, как это изменить. Ввёл в командной строке под администратором следующую команду:

reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\WebProjects /v Use64BitIISExpress /t REG_DWORD /d 1

Снова запустил отладку. IIS Express теперь запускается, как 64-разрядный. Но отладка всё равно не работает, а мне выдаёт ту же ошибку.

Помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 устарел, обновите до 2022, и да вам нужна x64 студия. А MSIE уже давно умер и похоронен майкрософтом, сейчас актуален Edge (`WebView2`). Да и IIS уже не панацея, многие используют облегчённый Kestrel. x86 тоже всё, потому что процессоров, не имеющих поддержки x64 больше не осталось.